# Can anyone spy on my traffic if they know my MAC address, local and public IP?

Tags: ip, tracking

If we are under the same ISP or different ISP? image for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are connected to your personal or ISP-issued router, then they are considered to be in *your* network, and might be able to read all of the traffic meant for you.

If they are a neighbor who happens to have the same ISP as you, and use their own personal or ISP-issued router, then they are not in your network, and the only way that they can see any traffic related to your computer is if you sent that information to them.

In most modern setups, your ISP will have a router somewhere in your neighborhood, and will send your traffic directly from their neighborhood router to your own router. If your computer is physically connected to the router, then in most cases, the router will send the traffic directly to your computer.  If you have someone malicious who is also physically connected to the router, they can make the switch broadcast your traffic to all ports, rather just the port connected to your computer.  If you're both connected through wireless, then you can't assume any privacy, either.  However, someone who is connected through wireless is not going to be able to eavesdrop on someone with a physical connection, and vice-versa.

The only way that someone can snoop on your traffic without being connected directly (through a physical wire or through wifi) to your router, is if they have somehow compromised the router in your neighborhood, or have compromised other routers in the ISP's network... but the further away the attack is, the less of their traffic they'll be able to intercept.

Answer (score 0):

Someone from outside your network cannot access your local IP or MAC address, so those do not factor into anything.

So, the question is if someone can 'spy' on your traffic knowing just your public IP. If they can get access to your traffic, then yes, they can identify your "stream" from the IP. But they would have to be very specifically placed to even be able to do that. Just knowing IP does not mean anything.

Comment: Is there any chance if we are under same network??

Comment: If you are both on the same network, then they can do a lot more, including spy on all your traffic, if the conditions were right.

Comment: Can you give more information(any books,article references) about how they do it?? someone doing this to me :'(

Comment: The term you are looking for is "man in the middle attack" if they are on the same network. Or, they can just sniff your traffic to see what sites you are visting.

Comment: It sounds plausible that the OP is experiencing a "man in the middle"-attack.

Comment: @Henrik it's not clear what the OP is experiencing

Answer (score 0):

Your local IP and MAC address only matters within your network, so they have no value for anyone wanting to spy on your traffic.

With your public address, anyone with access to any bit of internet traffic can identify your traffic, but only the traffic that passes their point of access - as an example, I would be able to see if you visited any of the websites we host at work, but I wouldn't be able to see your traffic to disney.com.

whether any other customers with your ISP can see any of your traffic depends on the technology you use to access the internet, and how the ISP has configured their things, some access technologies uses shared media, in those cases the traffic technically might pass others (but then it also depends on cabling).

Comment: But someone under same network knows every site I visit. Is this possible ?? He knows about only those thing.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*under* the same network", if there's no router between two computers, normal terminology is that they are *on* the same network. You also haven't said anything about the network you're experiencing this on, so all we can say is: Yes, that's possible - but that is just a statement of theoretical possibility.

Comment: We are under same switches and same router.

Comment: *Under* still doesn't mean anything related to network equipment (except physically, but I'm guessing that's not the case here).

Comment: Maybe! I am not sure about it. But thanks for the help :)